# Why does processing file with one very long single line as input give different numbers of records?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I use Spark 1.2.1 (in `local` mode) to extract and process log information from a file.

The size of the file could be more than 100Mb. The file contains a very long single line so I'm using regular expression to split this file into log data rows.

**MyApp.java**

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<String> txtFileRdd = sc.textFile(filename);
JavaRDD<MyLog> logRDD = txtFileRdd.flatMap(LogParser::parseFromLogLine).cache();
```

**LogParser.java**

```
public static Iterable<MyLog> parseFromLogLine(String logline) {
        List<MyLog> logs = new LinkedList<MyLog>();
        Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(logline);
        while (m.find()) {          
            logs.add(new MyLog(m.group(0)));            
        }   
        System.out.println("Logs detected " + logs.size());
        return logs;
}
```

Actual size of the processed file is about 100 Mb and it actually contains `323863` log items.

When I use Spark to extract my log items from file I get `455651` [`logRDD.count()`] log items which is not correct.

I think it happens because of file partitions, checking the output I see the following:

```
Logs detected 18694  
Logs detected 113104  
Logs detected 323863
```

And the total sum is `455651`!

So I see that my partitions are merged with each other keeping duplicate items and I'd like to prevent that behaviour.

The workaround is using `repartition(1)` as follows:

```
txtFileRdd.repartition(1).flatMap(LogParser::parseFromLogLine).cache();
```

That does give me the desired result `323863`, but I doubt that it's good for performance.

How to do the processing better performance-wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The partitioning is line-based by default. This fails in an interesting way when there is a single very long line, it seems. You could consider filing a bug for this (maybe there is one already).

The splitting is performed by the Hadoop file API, specifically the `TextInputFormat` class. One option is to specify your own `InputFormat` (which could include your entire parser) and use `sc.hadoopFile`.

Another option is to set a different delimiter via `textinputformat.record.delimiter`:

```
// Use space instead of newline as the delimiter.
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", " ")
```

Comment: Great answer @daniel-darabos! Thanks!
This issue seems to be a bug so I created a ticket in JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7001
Unfortunately, solution with textinputformat.record.delimiter does not allow me to extract log information as it splits the log neither. Another solution with InputFormat looks pretty good but I couldn't find any sample how to specify it properly

Comment: I agree that it should be part of the answer, but I've never made a custom `InputFormat` and only have a very vague idea about. Sorry. You could look at [Rot13InputFormat](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/release-1.1.0/itests/util/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/io/udf/Rot13InputFormat.java) as a tiny example and  https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/understand-recordreader-inputsplit/ for a good in-depth explanation of the line-based `RecordReader`. (Though you won't need much of that complexity, because your records don't span files.)